# How can I queue a .wav file in pygame mixer and then play that file in a loop? I cannot use time.sleep or any loops because of GUI blocking

Tags: python, pygame, guizero

I'm currently having trouble with pygame's mixer. I am trying to queue a file ("Ex1.wav") to play in pygame for an app that i'm trying to make. I want to loop Ex2.wav after the previous audio files ("Ex2.wav") have played, but I cannot use a `while` or `for` loop because I am using GuiZero, which cannot have loops because it blocks the GUI. Maybe a code example is a bit easier to understand what I'm trying to get across.

```
pygame.mixer.music.load("Ex2.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.play(10)
pygame.mixer.music.queue("Ex1.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
```

This does not achieve this. I've tried.
I want to make it so that Ex1.wav is not played and looped until after Ex2.wav is done. Like I said, I cannot use `while` or `for` loops due to GUI blocking, and I also cannot use `time.sleep()` or any other wait commands for the same reason.

If there isn't an easily made solution for this, I understand.

Comment: as per the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.queue) your given example should work as intended

Comment: For me, I do not know why, but it doesn't. The file that Ex2 substitutes is 3 beeps and they play infinitely after I execute the first `play` line. Thank you in any case for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python [Threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) might solve your problem

just create a function and execute it in separate thread so your GUI won't freeze
in iteration

```
import threading

def music_player ():
     for music in your_musics_list:
        pygame.mixer.music.load(music)
        pygame.mixer.music.play(10)

th = threading.Thread(target=music_player)

try:
    th.start()
except:
    pass
```

Thanks to @mattiiss for fixing my issue

Comment: hi @Matiiss yes it's non-blocking but you can block a thread as you wish
I think we should wait and see will my solution help Dryeet2704 or not
I'll delete my solution If It dosen't help

Comment: I tested it with a simple loop and printing a text, it worked
but your totally right I changed it
@Matiiss